# How to handle ngOptions data source which depends on a function in scope whose existence is predicated on the completion of a promise?

Tags: angularjs

In the following simple controller using ngResource:

```
controllers.controller('mappingsCtrl', function ($scope, $q, mappingsResource, databasesResource, tablesResource, fieldsResource) {
    $scope.databases = databasesResource.get();

    $scope.tables = tablesResource.get(function (response) {
        var tablesByDatabaseId = _.groupBy(response, 'DatabaseId');
        $scope.getTables = function (databaseId) {
            return tablesByDatabaseId[databaseId];
        }
    });

    $scope.fields = fieldsResource.get();

    $scope.fieldMappings = mappingsResource.get();
});
```

I am waiting until the tables resource returns before adding the function `getTables` to scope and in my markup I have a repeater with an ngOptions that depends on it.

```
<tr ng-repeat="mapping in fieldMappings" ng-cloak>
                <td>{{fields[mapping.FieldId]}}</td>
                <td><select ng-model="mapping.DatabaseId" ng-options="c.DatabaseId as c.DatabaseName for c in databases"></select></td>
                <td><select ng-model="mapping.TableId" ng-options="c.TableId as c.TableName for c in getTables(mapping.DatabaseId)"></select></td>
            </tr>
```

When I run it, everything works, but I suspected it might only be working due to timing "luck", so I forced the tables resource to pause 5 seconds before returning.  To my surprise, I got no errors, and it simply rendered the page with no options filled in and then 5 seconds later filled them in.

My question is: am I handling the scenario correctly insofar as having an ngOptions data source depend on a function in scope whose existence is predicated on the completion of a promise of indeterminate time...?

Comment: Angular expressions are [forgiving](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression), so it's OK if things are `undefined`, whether it's the data source directly or whether it's a function.

Comment: have you tried wrapping your `ng-repeat` in a `ng-if` that is true only when the promise is fulfilled? (perhaps if getTables is not null/undefined)

Comment: that's an interesting idea Niel... would make code more explicit